# Parametrized new() expects "identifier"

Tags: record, freepascal

I found the following code in an old document (1977!) and need to run it. However I get the following error message from FreePascal (2.6.4, Win64) at the first 'new':

```
(14, 9) Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "TRUE" found
```

According to [this](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/new.html)('new') and [this](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu19.html#x43-500003.3.2)('record'), it should work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

```
program prog(input, output);
type ptr = ^node;
  node = record position: 1 .. 512; fathers: array [0.. 4] of ptr;
    case (* internal: *) boolean of
      true: (ub: (minus, undef, plus);
        left, right: 0..5;
        rank: 0.. 4);
      false: (present: boolean; pred, succ: ptr);
      end;

procedure initialize(level: integer);
var v: ptr;
begin if level > 0 then
  new(v,true)
else
  new(v,false);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you're calling the [`New`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/new.html) procedure passing boolean values into its second parameter which for Free Pascal compiler signals to choose this overload:

```
procedure New(var P: Pointer; Cons: TProcedure);
```

which is used for allocating objects, where the second `Cons` parameter is used for passing the object's constructor method. So in this case the compiler was expecting a method, not a boolean value.

Since you are not allocating objects but records, you can call the [`New`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/new.html) procedure just this way:

```
New(v);
```

Comment: Thanks, it compiles now, I just cannot really test it yet. I suppose the 'true', 'false' params where required in whatever old version they used, but they seem pointless anyway.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, I don't know the meaning of those boolean values, but I guess they were used to choose the variant part (the `case` part) of the record. In Free Pascal you will allocate both parts, but you access only one of them. That is you allocate the record and then either access `ub`, `left`, `right` and `rank` fields, or `present`, `pred` and `succ` fields.

Answer (score 3):

The code you are using is probably ISO Pascal. FPC 2.6.4 cannot handle this construct. FPC from svn trunk aka FPC 2.7.1 can when you compile using the command line switch `-Miso`. The boolean values passed to `new` gets a meaning as soon as you un-comment the symbol `internal`. When this so-called *tag-field* is present, it is initialized with the value passed to `new`.

Comment: Pity that this feature was dropped. It would be nice to tell the compiler that you want to allocate only a certain record variant part.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, so it seems the _tag-field_ could be used to provide some kind of run-time type information.

Comment: @TLama: The feature is not dropped, but simply not yet implemented in FPC.